# Solving ODE with power series

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, summation, power-series

In some old notes, I found an exercise in which it was asked to solve this ODE, in a neighbourhood of $x_0=1$:

$$xy''(x) - 3y(x) = 2x^2$$

I tried to solve it but I'm getting stuck. Let me show you what I tried:

$x_0=1$ is an ordinary point the ODE, so the solution should be like

$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(x-x_0)^n =\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n (x-1)^n$$

I computed the derivatives

$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n (x-1)^n$$

$$y'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} n a_n (x-1)^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} n a_n (x-1)^{n-1}$$

$$y''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} n(n-1) a_n (x-1)^{n-2}=\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} n(n-1) a_n (x-1)^{n-2}$$

And I substituted in the original ODE:

$$x \left(\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} n(n-1) a_n (x-1)^{n-2}\right) -3 \left( \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n (x-1)^n\right)=0$$

I carried the costants inside the symbols of sum.

$$\left(\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} n(n-1) x a_n (x-1)^{n-2}\right) - \left( \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} 3a_n (x-1)^n\right)=0$$

The obtained expression has two addenda. In order to keep the same power to each polynomial, I fixed some variables.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} n(n-1) x a_n (x-1)^{n-2} \implies t:=n-2 \implies \sum_{t=0}^{+\infty} (t+2)(t+1) x a_{t+2} (x-1)^{t} \implies \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (n+2)(n+1) x a_{n+2} (x-1)^{n}  $$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} 3a_n (x-1)^n \quad \text{no transformation needed}$$

Then I wrote the addenda again:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (n+2)(n+1) x a_{n+2} (x-1)^{n} - \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} 3a_n (x-1)^n = 0$$

Now I checked the bounds of sums, in order to have them common for each sum, and 
 I noticed that they are already ok. The summation becomes

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \{(n+2)(n+1) x a_{n+2}  - 3a_n\} (x-1)^n = 0$$

But now, that $x$ in the first addendum is getting me stuck.

Can anyone show me how to complete the exercise?

Thanks in advance to everyone, even for having read my post.

Comment: Write $x=(x-1)+1$

Comment: Simple. Working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y(x)=f(x)-\frac{2}{3}x^{2}-\frac{4}{9}x$
The equation becomes
$$xf''-3f=0$$
Now, let $\xi=2\sqrt{3(x-1)}$
Thus
$$\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}=\frac{36}{\xi^{2}}\frac{d^{2}}{d\xi^{2}}-\frac{36}{\xi^{3}}\frac{d}{d\xi}$$
and let $f(x)=\xi\eta(\xi)$
So
$$\xi^{2}\eta''+\xi\eta'-(1+\xi^{2})\eta(\xi)=0$$
Which is modified Bessel equation and the solution is
$$\eta(\xi)=c_{1}I_{1}(\xi)+c_{2}K_{1}(\xi)$$
Thus
$$y(x)=c_{1}2\sqrt{3}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^{m+1/2}}{m!(m+2)}(x-1)^{m+1}-\frac{2}{3}x^{2}-\frac{4}{9}x$$
And we set $c_{2}=0$ as $K_{1}(\xi)$ is not well behaived

Comment: Interesting: I'd like to know how you found the initial substitution. I'm playing with the formula without reaching the same change of function you wrote.

Comment: I've used the book by Kamke on the ordinary odes. Unfortunately, there is no English version as far as I know, however, if you know German or Russian, I can send you a djvu version on email!

Comment: Probably it's easier German one. Does exist, in this site, a system of private messaging? I'm a novice of this site, so sorry for further outoftopic comment :)